# Exact target Api Connectivity in Java

Tags: web-services, soap, salesforce, apache-axis, exacttarget

I tried the following link to connect the Enterprise API Service of Exact Target. I couldnt succeed.I used the Following site to implement basic Connection to Exact Target Api.

[Connecting to Exact Target Api using Axis 2](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/getting_started_developers_and_the_exacttarget_api/connecting_to_the_api_using_java_and_axis2/)

I get the Following error Log

```
   org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Login failed
at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:375)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
at com.exacttarget.wsdl.partnerapi.PartnerAPIStub.retrieve(PartnerAPIStub.java:1394)
at com.exacttarget.client.ETClient.main(ETClient.java:49)
```

Can you please tell me where the error persists? I have no clue in working with Axis 2. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Did you setup CLIENTID/CLIENTSECRET?

Please leave your questions [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer (I know you can't comment yet).

Comment: I am having the same problem. Where should I set up the clientid/client secret in my configuration?

Comment: @mickeymoon You need to register on https://code.exacttarget.com/, then go to "App Center" and create new "API Integration". For that, you need an account on Exacttarget Marketing Cloud.

Comment: and after that? when I have to set the username and password... WHAT IS THE USERNAME AND WHAT IS THE PASSWORD?